# Populating list with retention

Tags: powershell

Doing a few courses and wanted to determine a possibility. Below allows me to just add a generic item to a generic list. I allow it to repeat after completing, but obviously `$newItem` is then overwritten so this limits my list to 1 object.

```
do {
   $newItem = Read-Host "Add an item";

   $listItems = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
   $listItems.Add($newItem)

   $listItems 
}
while($run =1)
```

I'm just curious if there's a way to retain list items to essentially stack and stack until its told to remove? Just a brief answer is adequate, this will not be used for anything, just curiosity!

Comment: As an aside: Condition `$run = -1` is always `$True` because you're _assigning_ (`=`) value `1` to `$run` rather than _comparing_ it (`-eq`). The RHS of an assignment becomes its value when used as an expression.

Comment: I had the same thought, but this was the example I was handed so I rolled with it. So there's no significance to ```$run``` that asks for an assignment rather than a comparator? I just assumed it was something I didn't quite understand yet.

Comment: I don't understand your question about significance, but what the loop does is set `$run` to `1` after each execution of the loop body, and, because assignment `$run = 1` is treated as value `1` when the condition is evaluated, the loop keeps executing indefinitely (unless you use `break` in the loop body), because `1` is converted to Boolean `$True`.

Comment: Yeah I'm apparently really bad at asking clear questions, but I know what variable assignments and comparators are and how they differ, that's not the misconception. I assume then ```$run``` isn't a pre-packed variable with powershell then as I assumed and I'm unsure why this was used unless its just meant to be a Boolean hack or foreshadowing for a later lesson.

Comment: Correct - `$run` is not an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables).

Comment: Then I presume this is an error, as I screened ahead and see absolutely no mention of this variable elsewhere. Odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define list object outside the do/while loop. Like so:

```
$listItems = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
do {
   $newItem = Read-Host "Add an item";

   $listItems.Add($newItem)

   $listItems 
}
while($run =1)
```

Comment: Right you are which makes absolute perfect sense, thank you! Defining the list object inside the do/while loop means its existence is only valid in that instance of the loop.